Narrator's name in Durrell's Justine
The back cover of my copy of Lawrence Durrell's 1957–1962 The Alexandria Quartet refers to the narrator as L. G. Darley ("L. G. Darley attempts to reconcile himself with [sic] the end of his affair with the dark, passionate Justine"). But as far as I can tell, the narrator is not named anywhere in the first novel in the tetralogy, Justine. In the narrative, none of the other characters address him by name, so we never learn it. When he writes out his acceptance to a shooting party, his note is rendered:

mr —————— accepts with pleasure the kind invitation of mr —————— to a duck shoot on Lake Mareotis.
 Durrell, Lawrence. Justine. 1957, rev. 1962. The Alexandra Quartet pp. 13–203. With a new introduction by Jan Morris. London: Faber and Faber, 2012. p. 168.

Coming as it does very late in the novel, this withholding of the narrator's name confirms my belief that he is anonymous. Where does the name L. G. Darley come from? Does this character's name become apparent in the subsequent volumes of the quartet?


Does this character's name become apparent in the subsequent volumes of the quartet?

Yes, exactly: he's kept anonymous in the first volume, Justine, but is explicitly named in later volumes. As Wikipedia mentions, "Justine is narrated by an impoverished Irishman, not named in this novel, but who is referred to as "Darley" in the later novels of the quartet." Or from this summary: "The first novel in the tetralogy, Justine, is a deliberately cryptic journey through the recent past of a British teacher and aspiring writer, his name revealed in the later books as Darley." Sequels from other viewpoints are necessary because

 Darley, though a perfectly trustworthy narrator, had misinterpreted the meaning of all the key events.

From searching online texts of the other books, it seems that the name "Darley" appears for the first time in the middle of the second book Balthazar:

Mountolive turned a speculative and gentle eye upon me as I seized a plate, and then greeted me by name with evident relief. "Ah, Darley," he said, "for a moment I thought you were one of my secretaries. They've been following me around all evening. Spoiling my fun. [...]"


You forgot to include evidence that the character of Darley in the later books is the same person as the character in Justine.  Does Darley silently remember or talk about events that out of all the people in Alexandria, only the character in Justine would have experienced?

@M.A.Golding I haven't read any of the books in full, but from skimming on the Internet Archive, it seems that Justine and Balthazar both have the same first-person narrator and the continuity is obvious.
